# What is the difference between simple reflex and model-based agents?

Tags: comparison, intelligent-agent, simple-reflex-agents

What is the difference between simple reflex and model-based agents?

What is the role of the internal state in the case of model-based agents?

Answer (score 4):

A **simplex reflex** agent takes actions based on current situational experiences.

For example, if you set your smart bulb to turn on at some given time, let's say at 9 pm, the bulb won't recognize how the time is longer simply because that's the rule defined it follows.

A simple reflex agent doesn't compute complex computational problems nor exhibit intelligence.

A **model-based** agent takes actions based on historical situational experiences. It performs actions basing on its internal state.

The *internal state* of the model-based agent acts as a "knowledge base", which allows actions to be performed by representing of unobserved aspects of the current state depending on percept history nor historical situational experiences.

For instance, a research-based planetary system can predict the planet's climatical conditions or weather basing on some geo-information knowledge base.